# C# encrypt mongodb sub-document or sub collection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Using .Net C# I'm trying to encrypt sub document while inserting & decrypt same while reading.
I tried with CSFL but no use.

Could any one suggest the solution

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what CSFLE is designed for, in particular I mean auto encryption. Look at this [doc](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.15/reference/driver/crud/client_side_encryption/). You should specify your subSocument in schemaMap, in the provided example, `encryptedField` is a field that will be automatically encrypted during writing and decrypted during reading.

Comment: ````MongoDB.Driver.Encryption.MongoEncryptionException: 'Encryption related exception: Exception starting mongocryptd process. Is mongocryptd on the system path?.'
````
Facing above exception
- dododo

Comment: you should read the doc above, this error says that mongocryptd which is required process for auto encryption (and only available in enterprise server though) is not launched.

Comment: You can find how to do it in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70154963/unable-understand-how-to-install-libmongocrypt/70159362#70159362

Comment: it can be also launched automatically if the path to mongocryptd is added into your PATH env variable