# Exception starting mongocryptd process. Is `mongocryptd` on the system path?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, intellij-idea, path

I am trying to run a project on intellij idea but it is showing the following error.

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoDbFactory': Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mongoencryptionutil/config/CustomMongoClientConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception with message: Exception starting mongocryptd process. Is `mongocryptd` on the system path?
```

I have added /usr/local/bin/bin in path variables of the project and it has mongocryptd.. Still it is showing this error.

[image: System Settings]

Comment: You should add a path to mongocryptd binary into PATH. `/usr/local/bin/bin` doesn't look like correct path.

Comment: see also a #2 about mongocryptd configuration here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70154963/unable-understand-how-to-install-libmongocrypt/70159362#70159362

Comment: @dododo the path is correct .. I have checked it..it contains mongocryptd

Comment: Also i have tried running it manually..

Comment: with doubled `bin`? If you did everything correct, you can open any terminal in any folder and just type: `mongocryptd` and it should work

Comment: @dododo it shows command not found..

Comment: then you didn't add it to the $PATH, check what you have in the output here `echo $PATH`